# Rotate text using pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to rotate text using pdfbox by I couldn't achieve it. I tried to set the texMatrix but my text is not rotating as intended.

Does someone have an idea of how I could turn at 90 degrees my text?

This is my code :

```
contentStream.beginText();

 float tx = titleWidth / 2;
 float ty = titleHeight / 2;

contentStream.setTextMatrix(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(tx, ty)); 
contentStream.setTextMatrix(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(90),tx,ty));
contentStream.setTextMatrix(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(-tx, -ty));

 contentStream.newLineAtOffset(xPos, yPos);

contentStream.setFont(font, fontSize);
contentStream.showText("Tets");
contentStream.endText();
```

Thank You

Comment: I odn't know what you want to do, but the problem here is that "setTextMatrix" sets, instead of transforming the previous text matrix. Consider doing the matrix operations first, then passing that matrix only once.

Comment: Alternatively alter the current transformation matrix. The `transform` method does not set but it multiplies from the left. That being said, it is indeed not entirely clear where exactly you want to put the rotated text.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I already tried and it did not work

Comment: @mkl i want to draw rotate text at the xPos and the yPos, i don't want my text to move i just want it to turn around it center

Comment: The rotation is done around (0,0), which is at the bottom left. You need to visualize this by taking a sheet of paper, then rotating it, then thinking about what translation you need to make so that the text appears at the correct position. IMHO the translation to do after rotation is (0,-original paper width).

Comment: *"I just want it to turn around it center"* – you mean around the center of the horizontally written text with start at (xpos,ypos)? That would be at (xpos + tx,ypos + ty - descent), wouldn't it? Our do you mean that differently?

Comment: @mkl Yes that it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution that draws three pages, one with text unrotated, one with text rotated but keeping the coordinates as if planning landscape printing, and one that is what you wanted (rotated around the center of the text). My solution is close to that, it rotates around the bottom of the center of the text.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page1 = new PDPage();
    doc.addPage(page1);
    PDPage page2 = new PDPage();
    doc.addPage(page2);
    PDPage page3 = new PDPage();
    doc.addPage(page3);

    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    float fontSize = 20;
    int xPos = 100;
    int yPos = 400;
    float titleWidth = font.getStringWidth("Tets") / 1000;
    float titleHeight = fontSize;
    float tx = titleWidth / 2;
    float ty = titleHeight / 2;

    try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page1))
    {
        contentStream.beginText();

        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(xPos, yPos);

        contentStream.setFont(font, fontSize);
        contentStream.showText("Tets");
        contentStream.endText();
    }

    // classic case of rotated page
    try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page2))
    {
        contentStream.beginText();

        Matrix matrix = Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(90), 0, 0);
        matrix.translate(0, -page2.getMediaBox().getWidth());

        contentStream.setTextMatrix(matrix);

        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(xPos, yPos);

        contentStream.setFont(font, fontSize);
        contentStream.showText("Tets");
        contentStream.endText();
    }

    // rotation around text
    try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page3))
    {
        contentStream.beginText();

        Matrix matrix = Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(90), 0, 0);
        matrix.translate(0, -page3.getMediaBox().getWidth());

        contentStream.setTextMatrix(matrix);

        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(yPos - titleWidth / 2 - fontSize, page3.getMediaBox().getWidth() - xPos - titleWidth / 2 - fontSize);

        contentStream.setFont(font, fontSize);
        contentStream.showText("Tets");
        contentStream.endText();
    }
    doc.save("saved.pdf");
    doc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This example rotates around the left baseline of the text and uses the matrix translation to position the text at the specific point.
The `showText()` is always positioned at `0,0`, which is the position before the rotation. The matrix translation then positions the text after the rotation.

If you want another rotation point of your text relocation the text rotation position in the `contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, 0)`-line

```
float angle = 35;
double radians = Math.toRadians(angle);
for (int x : new int[] {50,85,125, 200}) 
  for (int y : new int[] {40, 95, 160, 300}) {
    contentStream.beginText();
    
    // Notice the post rotation position
    Matrix matrix = Matrix.getRotateInstance(radians,x,y);
    contentStream.setTextMatrix(matrix);

    // Notice the pre rotation position
    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, 0);

    contentStream.showText(".(" + x + "," + y + ")");
    contentStream.endText();
  }
```

To get the height and the width of the text you want to rotate use `font.getBoundingBox().getHeight()/1000*fontSize` and `font.getStringWidth(text)/1000*fontSize`.